# Firebase auth onCreate add dynamic custom claim

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to add some custom claims to my users, mainly *role* and *org* fields.

```
exports.userSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async user => {
  console.log(user);
  let uid = user.uid;
  await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { project_worker: true });
});
```

This is my current code. What I would like to do is be able to pass this onCreate method information to dynamically set a custom claim:

```
setCustomUserClaims(uid, { project_worker: true, org: userInput });
```

Is this possible? From what I have read you cannot pass data to the onCreate function, it just pulls the user information from firebase auth.

Is there another way I could go about doing this?

Comment: You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) *-disclaimer, I'm the author-* which explains how to use a Callable Cloud Function to create users. By following this approach you will be able to pass "information to dynamically set custom claims" (In the article we set some user roles but any other claim value can be used of course).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec This might be exactly what I need!
I was hoping for a simpler approach, possibly passing some JSON along with a user when it is created that could then populate custom claims. If that was supported it would be amazing.

I'm trying to avoid using firestore in terms of holding user info. I'd like to just have it in a single place.

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Be aware, however, to not "supercharge" you claims. As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#best_practices_for_custom_claims): "Custom claims are only used to provide access control. They are not designed to store additional data (such as profile and other custom data). ... it is strongly discouraged as these claims are stored in the ID token and could cause performance issues because all authenticated requests always contain a Firebase ID token corresponding to the signed in user."